# Why did 摩羅 also come to mean penis?

Tags: etymology, history

Is there any further implication to be gleaned from this and how did this meaning come to be? Is there any suggestion that the male genitals are somehow an obstacle to enlightenment?

Comment: Dictionary: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E9%AD%94%E7%BE%85#Japanese

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from 日本国語大辞典 entry:

> まら 【魔羅・摩羅】
>
> **(1)**「ま（魔）(1)」に同じ。
>
> ＊却癈忘記〔１２３５〕下「勤行之人の魔道に堕ると、世間に人のいふ事、甚謂有事也。魔と者具には魔羅と云ふ」
>
> **(2)**（(1)から転じたとも、排泄する意の「まる」の交替形ともいう）陰茎をいう。もと僧侶が用いた語。
>
> ＊霊異記〔８１０〜８２４〕中・一一「卒爾に（マラ）に蟻著きて嚼み〈国会図書館本訓釈  万良〉」

That means, the "penis" sense may have come from buddhist *māra*, or the verb まる "excrete", or confusion between both.